# nodejs start debugger on different port

Tags: linux, node.js, debugging

Im a little confused with all this nodejs debug syntax flying around.
I simply want to start the debugger on a process when I run it on a different port.

Normally I start debugging by `node debug file.js`

but now I have to process` running that I need to debug

Now I found the command `node --debugger=7873 file.js` but that starts the debugger and jumps past all the breaks and I tried `node --debugger=7837 --debug-brk file.js` but that forces me to consume another teminal window. How can I just run a script on a different port in the same terminal or with out using nohup?

Answer (score 1):

`node debug --port=[your port] your_program.js`

responsible _debugger code [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_debugger.js#L1645)